# How to down-weight older data in time series regression

Tags: regression, time-series, estimation, forecasting, transform

In a regression fit of vectors varying with time $t$
$\qquad y \sim [x_t\ x_{t-1}\ x_{t-2}\ ...] \cdot [c_t\ c_{t-1}\ c_{t-2} \ ...] $ ,
how can one down-weight the older $x_t$ to model "older is less relevant" (than the regression gives) ?
Say that rows in data matrix $X$ are observables (stocks, market segments ...)
and columns are times.
Correct me, 
[Weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Weighted_linear_least_squares)
weights rows; how does one weight columns, times ?

Added:
Down-weighting older data in time series looks complex, much more so than
linear least squares with i.i.d. errors in rows (observations) --
just divide through by $\sigma_i$; or
classification  with i.i.d. errors in columns (e.g. features) --
just centre each column.
Can anyone say either

- yes, I downweight time series; here are some examples on the web
- no: down-weighting time series *is* complex, not for novices.

(http://AndrewGelman.com/2005/06/21/timeseries_regr  discussed this question 10 years ago,
mentioning Kalman filters and hierarchical Bayes, but with no examples.)

Answer (score 2):

A common method is to use an exponentially weighted cost function:
$$ \sum_i \lambda^{i} e(t-i)^2 $$
where $e(t)$ is the residual error, and $\lambda$ is the forgetting rate. If $\lambda=1$, you get back least squares regression.

You can use [*recursive least squares* (RLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) to find a solution efficiently.

Comment: Thanks; if you could point to an example, I'll accept. Also on RLS, wouldn't nonlinear least squares aka LevMar be simpler, and fast enough ?

Comment: What kind of example? There are tons of papers using RLS. You want a reference? Also, why nonlinear LS and Levenberg-Marquardt? This cost function is quadratic, and RLS is very simple to implement.

Comment: A runnable example on the web, preferably with real data; python would be nice. Sure there are lots of papers, but is the method ever used in practice ? Also off-the-shelf and stable [scipy.leastsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-square-fitting-leastsq) is simple.